# Handling query strings in bundled JavaScripts

Tags: javascript, external

I have a bunch of external JavaScript I want to load onto a  web site.

For example, I've added script tags with the following sources:

src 1: `google.com/gtm.js?id=123456`

src 2: `facebook.com/facebook-sdk.js`

src 3: `youtube.com/youtube-sdk`

(...)

How would I go about bundling a series of files when they depend on their query parameters to work?

For instance, `gtm.js` will not work unless it is loaded as part of a script whose source has the query parameter `?id=123`.

How would I handle multiple scripts with the same query parameter (e.g., `id`?)

Is there a way to get these query parameters incorporated into the bundle?